# What is the log form of this equation?

Tags: logarithms

I want to find the log form of this equation to simplify some of the subsequent steps. However, I am struggling with how to handle the constant, $\theta$. If anyone could explain how to log this equation, it would be much appreciated:

$$
\Pi_t^{1-\varepsilon} = \theta + (1-\theta) (P_t^{*}/P_{t-1})^{1-\varepsilon} 
$$

If theta were excluded, so that the equation was $\Pi_t^{1-\varepsilon} = (1-\theta) (P_t^{*}/P_{t-1})^{1-\varepsilon}$, I would understand the log form to be:

$$
(1-\varepsilon)\ln\Pi_t = \ln(1-\theta) + (1-\varepsilon)\ln(P_t^{*}/P_{t-1})
$$

Comment: Is $\Pi_t^{1-\varepsilon}$ a product (if so, of what?) or a constant?

Comment: Hi, it is a variable that changes over time t. It is an aggregate price index at time t

Comment: I don't believe there's any way of simplifying the logarithm of the RHS in general. Ignoring subscripts, we have $\ln(\mathrm{RHS})=\ln\left(\theta+\left(1-\theta\right)\left(\frac{P^*}{P}\right)^{1-\varepsilon}\right)$ but $\log(a+b)$ does not simplify in general.